# Display Percentage of grouped SUM to total SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I currently have results like

```
total sales | total cost | total profit | department
----------------------------------------------------
100          50            50             A
80           20            60             B
250          120           130            C
```

Using columns from tables

*Invoice_Itemized*

```
itemnum | costper | priceper | quantity | invoice_number
--------------------------------------------------------
```

*Invoice_Totals*

```
invoice_number | datetime
---------------------------
```

*Inventory*

```
itemnum | dept_id
------------------
```

*Departments*

```
 dept_id | description  
 ----------------------
```

with the following code

```
select sum(invoice_itemized.priceper* invoice_itemized.quantity) as "Total Sales",

sum(invoice_itemized.quantity*inventory.cost) as "Total Cost", 

sum(invoice_itemized.priceper* invoice_itemized.quantity)- 
sum(invoice_itemized.quantity*inventory.cost) as "Total Profit", 

departments.description as Department

from invoice_itemized, invoice_totals, inventory, departments

where invoice_itemized.invoice_number=invoice_totals.invoice_number

and year(invoice_totals.datetime)=2018 and month(invoice_totals.datetime)=10

and inventory.itemnum=invoice_itemized.itemnum 

and inventory.dept_id=departments.dept_id

and departments.description<>'shop use'

and departments.description<>'none'

and departments.description<>'ingredients'

group by departments.description

order by "total profit" desc
```

I would like results like

```
total sales | total cost | total profit | percentage total profit | department
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
100          50            50                     20.83                 A
80           20            60                      25                   B
250          120           130                    54.17                 C
```

The problem I encounter is that I'm trying to divide a the grouped results of a SUM-SUM by the total of the same SUM-SUM. I've tried something similar to the suggestion made in

[Percentage from Total SUM after GROUP BY SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909494/percentage-from-total-sum-after-group-by-sql-server)

but that didn't seem to work for me. I was getting binding errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: _Why_ didn't it work?  What did you get instead?  Side note:  Please explicitly list out your `JOIN`s, and put as many conditions in the `ON` clause as possible, rather than using the comma-separated `FROM` clause, it's much easier to read and reason about.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with window functions:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*,
       profit * 100.0 / sum(profit) over () as profit_percentage
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Select q.[Total Sales],
    q.[Total Cost],
    q.[Total Profit],
    q.Total Profit] / q1.Total Profit] as [Percentage Total Profit],
    q.Department
from (
    select sum(invoice_itemized.priceper* invoice_itemized.quantity) as [Total Sales],
        sum(invoice_itemized.quantity*inventory.cost) as [Total Cost], 
        sum(invoice_itemized.priceper* invoice_itemized.quantity) - sum(invoice_itemized.quantity*inventory.cost) as [Total Profit], 
        departments.description as Department
    from invoice_itemized, invoice_totals, inventory, departments
    where invoice_itemized.invoice_number=invoice_totals.invoice_number
        and year(invoice_totals.datetime)=2018 and month(invoice_totals.datetime)=10
        and inventory.itemnum=invoice_itemized.itemnum 
        and inventory.dept_id=departments.dept_id
        and departments.description<>'shop use'
        and departments.description<>'none'
        and departments.description<>'ingredients'
    group by departments.description) q
join (
    select sum(t.[Total Profit]) as [Total Profit]
    from (select sum(invoice_itemized.priceper* invoice_itemized.quantity) as [Total Sales],
        sum(invoice_itemized.quantity*inventory.cost) as [Total Cost], 
        sum(invoice_itemized.priceper* invoice_itemized.quantity) - sum(invoice_itemized.quantity*inventory.cost) as [Total Profit], 
        departments.description as Department
    from invoice_itemized, invoice_totals, inventory, departments
    where invoice_itemized.invoice_number=invoice_totals.invoice_number
        and year(invoice_totals.datetime)=2018 and month(invoice_totals.datetime)=10
        and inventory.itemnum=invoice_itemized.itemnum 
        and inventory.dept_id=departments.dept_id
        and departments.description<>'shop use'
        and departments.description<>'none'
        and departments.description<>'ingredients'
    group by departments.description) t
) q1 on q1.[Total Profit] = q1.[Total Profit]
order by q.[Total Profit] desc
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ']'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near 'q'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near 'q1'.

Comment: @RedDevil i missed a square bracket :) q.[Total Profit]/q1.[Total Profit]

Comment: That'll do it! Thank you both