# SQL count distinct per group divided by count distinct of total

Tags: sql, distinct

I have:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |
| 1 | 124 |
| 1 | 125 |
| 2 | 126 |
| 2 | 127 |
| 2 | 127 |
| 3 | 128 |
| 3 | 128 |
| 3 | 128 |

I want an aggregation like:

| id | distinct_count | total_distinct | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 6 | 0.33 |
| 3 | 1 | 6 | 0.167 |

I tried applying a window over clause like this:

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT value) AS distinct_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT value) OVER () AS total_distinct,
       COUNT(DISTINCT value) / COUNT(DISTINCT value) OVER () AS percentage
FROM have
GROUP BY id
```

but it seems it is not implemented yet.

is there a way to achieve this without a join?

Comment: what result did you get?

Comment: i got an error.. DISTINCT in window function parameters not yet supported

Comment: see this SO as an example of SUM aggregation that works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909494/percentage-from-total-sum-after-group-by-sql-server

Comment: Why the question? If you can find an answer yourself within 10 minutes ?

Comment: not sure what you mean @Luuk . i can't find the answer, hence the q

Comment: Is the link you just send not an answer to your question ? Please clarify

Comment: the link shows how you would do this for SUM aggregation. it does not work for COUNT(DISTINCT ...)  because it is not implemented as yet

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT value) AS distinct_count,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value) FROM have) AS total_distinct,
       (0.0+COUNT(DISTINCT value)) / (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value) FROM have) AS percentage
FROM have
GROUP BY id
```

or do:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value) AS value FROM have)
SELECT 
       id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT value) AS distinct_count,
       cte.value AS total_distinct,
       (0.0+COUNT(DISTINCT value)) / cte.value AS percentage
FROM have
CROSS APPLY cte
GROUP By cte.value,id;
```

Comment: Thanks! Was too focused on OVER clause for some reason

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to enumerate the values and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_iv = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as distinct_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_v = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total_distinct_count,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_iv = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END) /
        SUM(CASE WHEN seqnum_v = 1 THEN 1.0 ELSE 0 END)
       ) as ratio
FROM (SELECT h.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, value ORDER BY value) as seqnum_iv,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY value) as seqnum_v
      FROM have h
     ) h
GROUP BY id;
```

This may be faster than an approach using subqueries.

Comment: Thank you, I'll defs compare runtime seeing as it is on large'ish transactional data.

Comment: @Grizzly2501 . . . I missed something the first time I answered.  I have fixed the answer.