# How to get percentage from Total SUM SQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables to calculate payments, received and paid:

1. Company

| idcompany | company |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLE |
| 2 | GOOGLE |
| 3 | MICROSOFT |
| 4 | STEAM |
| 5 | AMAZON |
| 6 | LG |

2. Pay:

| id | company | dueday | valuep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | APPLE | 03/10/2022 | 200,00 |
| 2 | APPLE | 04/10/2022 | 600,00 |
| 3 | GOOGLE | 04/10/2022 | 600,00 |
| 4 | MICROSOFT | 04/10/2022 | 500,00 |
| 5 | MICROSOFT | 04/10/2022 | 60,00 |
| 6 | APPLE | 04/10/2022 | 100,00 |

3.Receive:

| idconta | company | issuedate | valuer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | MICROSOFT | 03/10/2022 | 70000,00 |
| 106 | STEAM | 03/10/2022 | 15000,00 |
| 107 | STEAM | 03/10/2022 | 42000,00 |
| 108 | AMAZON | 03/10/2022 | 46000,00 |
| 109 | LG | 03/10/2022 | 3200,00 |

I tried this query to make a report with amount paid and received during a certain period and the percentage of value received/total value.

I need a report with amount paid and received during a certain period and percentage of value received under total amount:

| idconta | company | issuedate | valuer | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 104 | MICROSOFT | 03/10/2022 | 70000,00 | 39% (70000/176200) |
| 106 | STEAM | 03/10/2022 | 15000,00 | 8% (15/176200) |
| 107 | STEAM | 03/10/2022 | 42000,00 | 23% (42000/176200) |
| 108 | AMAZON | 03/10/2022 | 46000,00 | 26% (46000/176200) |
| 109 | LG | 03/10/2022 | 3200,00 | 1% (32000/176200) |
| Total |  |  | 176200,00 | ------------------- |

I tried `SUM(valuer) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(valuer)) OVER () AS Percentage` as suggested in [Percentage from Total SUM after GROUP BY SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909494/percentage-from-total-sum-after-group-by-sql-server) but did not work.
Query that is not working below and fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/JHHomMi3

```
SELECT o.company, value_pay, value_receive 
FROM app_company AS o 
LEFT JOIN  (select sum(valuep) as value_pay,company from app_pay 
  where date(dueday) BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-30' group by company) 
  AS n ON o.company=n.company 
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT SUM(valuer)  AS value_receive,  
  SUM(valuer) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(valuer)) OVER () AS Percentage, 
  company from app_receive
 where date(issuedate) BETWEEN '2022-10-01' AND '2022-10-30'group by company)
  AS r ON o.company=r.company order by o.company asc;
```

Comment: No calculation of your values can bring to 179400. Where did you get that number from?

Comment: Your specification is not clear. Your `app_pay` table doesn't seem to contribute any data to your sample result set. And, it's not clear what you want to do about aggregating by month.. Please [edit] your question to explain your business rules.

Comment: I need a report with amount paid and received during a certain period and percentage of value received under total amount. Only percentage with  SUM OVER () is not working. The post is updated too

Comment: Please amend your desired outcome to include amount paid.

Answer (score 0):

You've got some table unused in your example, but `SUM … OVER()` is indeed the way to go:

```sql
SELECT 
  c.company, 
  CONCAT(
    ROUND(
      SUM(IFNULL(r.valuer, 0)) * 100.0 / SUM(r.valuer) OVER (), 2), 
    '%') AS percent
FROM app_company c
LEFT JOIN app_receive r ON c.company = r.company
GROUP BY c.company, r.valuer

-- (company)    (percent)
-- APPLE        0%
-- GOOGLE       0%
-- MICROSOFT    39.73%
-- STEAM        23.84%
-- STEAM        8.51%
-- AMAZON       26.11%
-- LG           1.82%
```

Dataset used:

```sql
CREATE TABLE app_company (
  idcompany INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  company TEXT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO app_company VALUES
(1, 'APPLE'),
(2, 'GOOGLE'),
(3, 'MICROSOFT'),
(4, 'STEAM'),
(5, 'AMAZON'),
(6, 'LG');

CREATE TABLE app_receive (
  idconta INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  company TEXT NOT NULL,
  issuedate DATE NOT NULL,
  valuer FLOAT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO app_receive VALUES 
(104,   'MICROSOFT',    '2022-10-03',   70000.00),
(106,   'STEAM',        '2022-10-03',   15000.00),
(107,   'STEAM',        '2022-10-03',   42000.00),
(108,   'AMAZON',       '2022-10-03',   46000.00),
(109,   'LG',           '2022-10-03',   3200.00);
```